# How to change the location of jackrabbit repository on the filesystem and migrate existing content?

Tags: apache, tomcat, repository, jackrabbit, jcr

I have run into a bit of a fix. I installed Apache on C drive (with space 40 GB) and installed jackrabbit as my document management system. Due to high usage, the drive is almost full and I now need to move the contents to another drive before I run out of space on C drive. Is this possible? If so how ? 
I need to be able to change the settings in such a way that all my previously uploaded documents are available as well as newly uploaded documents are uploaded to the new location.

Comment: I solved the issue. I stopped Apache Tomcat service. I moved the folder 'workspaces' inside the 'jackrabbit' folder to new location 'E:\JackrabbitWorkspace\workspaces'. 

Then edited the value to <Workspaces rootPath="E:\JackrabbitWorkspace\workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/> in repository.xml